# Two messages in a ring of N process in C with pipes

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

I implement a Ring of N generation like this.

```
 (process 0)--pipe4--(process 3)
   |                    |
   |                    |
   pipe 1              pipe 3
   |                    |
   |                    |
 (process 1)--pipe2--(process 2)
```

So, the Process 0 is the father of process 1, the process 1 the father of process 2 etc...

The process 0 send a random number to process 1 via pipe1, process 1 generate an other random number, and send max between these two numbers to process 2 via pipe 2 etc...

The proess 0 is reading on the pipe4, so he is blocked, waiting for the last message, then show the winner.

What i want to do, is that the process 0 send the winner to all the process now.

I try to re-read the pipe on each process to make them lock until the answer is propagated but a re read in the same process for the same pipe => no block.

So i try to create an other pipe between each process for the communication of the winner. So after i send the random number, i read on the pipeWinner, but this not block the process too!!

i'm really confuse, i don"t know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct Node {
      int node;
      int val;
      int pid;
    };


    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

      //Generation correspond to the number of generation the user want to create
      int nbGeneration = atoi(argv[1]);
      int indexGeneration=1;

      //This value store the new random created on each generation
      int newValue=0;
      int pid=0;

      //Array of pipe
      int tube[nbGeneration][2];
      int tubeAnswer[nbGeneration-1][2];

      //Our seed for the rand
      int seed=time(NULL);
      srand(seed);

      //The struct for the first process
      //Value initialize here
      struct Node processInitiale;
      processInitiale.node=0;
      processInitiale.val =rand();
      processInitiale.pid =getpid();

      //The struct for the childs process, this struct store the winner too
      struct Node processWinner;
      processWinner.node=0;
      processWinner.val =0;
      processWinner.pid =0;

      //Pipe the nbGeneration pipe for the inital process reading
      pipe(tube[nbGeneration]);

      //Create N generation
      for(indexGeneration = 1 ; indexGeneration < nbGeneration; ++indexGeneration )
      {
        pipe(tube[indexGeneration]);
        pipe(tubeAnswer[indexGeneration]);
        pid = fork();
        if(pid==-1)
        {
          printf("%s\n", "Erreur lors de la création du processus");
        }
        if(pid!=0)
        {
          if(indexGeneration==1) // Initial process - Write first value to the first child
          {
            close(tube[indexGeneration][0]);
            write(tube[indexGeneration][1],&processInitiale,sizeof(processInitiale));
            close(tube[indexGeneration][1]);

            //This read is "bloquant", we gonna wait for the last children
            close(tube[nbGeneration][1]);
            read(tube[nbGeneration][0],&processWinner,sizeof(processWinner));
            close(tube[nbGeneration][0]);

            //Show result
            printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d\n", "Processus PID: ",processInitiale.pid, " node ", processInitiale.node ," value: ",  processInitiale.val);
            printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%s%d\n","Node: ",processInitiale.node," Winner is: ",processWinner.val," NODE: ",processWinner.node," PID: ",processWinner.pid );
          }
          break;
        }
        else if(pid==0) //If it's the children, let's read the precedent pipe, then write into the next pipe for the next children
        {
            //Reading in the precedent pipe (The first one was writtend by the initial process - so this one is lock in the case children execute before first father)
            close(tube[indexGeneration][1]);
            read(tube[indexGeneration][0],&processWinner,sizeof(processWinner));
            close(tube[indexGeneration][0]);
            //Creation on the new random value to compare
            newValue = rand();
            printf("%s%ld%s%d%s%d\n", "Processus PID: ",(long)getpid(), " node ", indexGeneration ," value: ",  newValue);

            //Compare, if more bigger, change the struct
            if(newValue>processWinner.val)
            {
              processWinner.node= indexGeneration;
              processWinner.val = newValue;
              processWinner.pid = getpid();
            }

            //Write data into the next pipe for the next children
            //The last children gonna write for the inital process at least
            close(tube[indexGeneration+1][0]);
            write(tube[indexGeneration+1][1],&processWinner,sizeof(processWinner));
            close(tube[indexGeneration+1][1]);

            //Trying to read in the pipeAnswer but this one didn't block my process.
            close(tubeAnswer[indexGeneration][0]);
            read(tubeAnswer[indexGeneration][1],&processWinner,sizeof(processWinner));
            close(tubeAnswer[indexGeneration][1]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Note that each process will generate the same random number under the regime you've got.  Each child process probably needs to seed with its process ID (since those will be unique) after the fork, to ensure you get different values from each process.  You should be using more functions, not a single monolithic `main()`.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <time.h>`  for the `time()` function.

Comment: should never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.

Comment: the function: `time()` does not return a `int`.   The function: `srand()` is expecting a `unsigned int`, not an `int`.

Comment: when calling the function: `pipe()`,  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: closing the `write to` end of a pipe can result in the `read from` end of the pipe not being readable.

Comment: in the posted code for the child, it seems the code is trying both read and write to the input end of the associated pipe.  That will not work

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up producing for this.  I originally worked on it back in 2017, but recently another question appeared that had similar issues with a circle of pipes.

Source code: `pipe97.c` — compiled to executable `pipe97`.

```
/* SO 4626-6329 */
/*
**   (process 0)--pipe0--(process 3)
**     |                    |
**     |                    |
**    pipe1                pipe3
**     |                    |
**     |                    |
**   (process 1)--pipe2--(process 2)
**
** So, the Process 0 is the parent of process 1; process 1 the
** parent of process 2; etc...
**
** Process 0 sends a random number to process 1 via pipe1; process 1
** generate an other random number, and send max between these two
** numbers to process 2 via pipe 2; etc...
**
** Process 0 is reading on pipe4, so it is blocked, waiting for
** the last message, then show the winner.
**
** What I want to do, is that the process 0 send the winner to all the
** process now.
**
** ********************************************************************
**
** Designate the 4 processes P0..P3.
** Designate the 4 pipes (channels) C0..C3.
**
** C0 must be created by P0 before creating P1.
** C1 must be created by P0 before creating P1.
** C2 must be created by P0 before creating P1 (because P1 needs to write to it).
** C3 must be created by P0 before creating P2 (because P2 needs to write to it).
** P0 will write to  C1 and read from C0.
** P1 will read from C1 and write to  C2.
** P2 will read from C2 and write to  C3.
** P3 will read from C3 and write to  C0.
**
** Hence Pn always reads from Cn and writes to C((n+1)%4).
** P0 writes then reads; the other processes read then write.
** Note that P1 and P2 should close C0 after forking the next child.
** PN (for N > 1) should close C1..C(N-1) too (it should be sufficient
** to close C(N-1) since P(N-1) closed the prior channels).
**
** Although the code does not rely on detecting EOF, the pipes will be
** closed, even though it is not crucial to the correct functioning of
** this program.
*/

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Node
{
    int node;
    int val;
    int pid;
};

static void no_children(void)
{
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("PID %5d: child %5d exited 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
}

static void check_fds(void)
{
    struct stat sb;
    char buffer[128];
    char *bufptr = buffer;
    int n = snprintf(bufptr, sizeof(buffer), "PID %5d: ", (int)getpid());
    bufptr += n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (fstat(i, &sb) != 0)
            *bufptr++ = '-';
        else
            *bufptr++ = 'o';
    }
    *bufptr++ = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    fflush(stdout);
}

static void pr_result(const char *tag, const struct Node *result)
{
    char buffer[16];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.12s:", tag);
    printf("%-13s PID = %5d, PPID = %5d, Node = %d (PID %5d), Value = %5d\n", buffer,
           (int)getpid(), (int)getppid(), result->node, result->pid, result->val);
    fflush(stdout);
}

static inline int new_bid(void)
{
    return rand() % 10000;
}

static inline void pr_channel(int i, int c[2])
{
    printf("%5d: C%d(%d,%d)\n", (int)getpid(), i, c[0], c[1]);
    fflush(stdout);
}

static inline void mk_channel(int i, int c[2])
{
    if (pipe(c) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to create pipe %d, (%d: %s)\n",
                (int)getpid(), i, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pr_channel(i, c);
}

static _Noreturn void be_parental(int i_pipe[2], int o_pipe[2])
{
    int pid = getpid();
    struct Node proc0 = { 0, new_bid(), pid };
    struct Node winner = { 0, 0, 0 };
    printf("PID %5d (PPID %5d): parent at work\n", pid, (int)getppid());
    printf("FD {%d, %d, %d, %d}\n", i_pipe[0], i_pipe[1], o_pipe[0], o_pipe[1]);
    check_fds();

    pr_result("Opening bid", &proc0);
    close(o_pipe[0]);
    printf("Writing opening bid to fd %d\n", o_pipe[1]);
    if (write(o_pipe[1], &proc0, sizeof(proc0)) != sizeof(proc0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to write entry to fd %d (%d: %s)\n",
                pid, o_pipe[1], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(i_pipe[1]);
    if (read(i_pipe[0], &winner, sizeof(winner)) != sizeof(winner))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to read entry from fd %d (%d: %s)\n",
                pid, i_pipe[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //close(i_pipe[0]);

    pr_result("Winning node", &winner);
    if (write(o_pipe[1], &winner, sizeof(winner)) != sizeof(winner))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to write entry to fd %d (%d: %s)\n",
                pid, o_pipe[1], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(o_pipe[1]);

    /* Read final result once more */
    if (read(i_pipe[0], &winner, sizeof(winner)) != sizeof(winner))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to read entry from fd %d (%d: %s)\n",
                pid, i_pipe[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(i_pipe[0]);
    pr_result("Recirculated", &winner);

    no_children();
    check_fds();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

static _Noreturn void be_childish(int i, int i_pipe[2], int o_pipe[2])
{
    struct Node winner;
    int pid = getpid();
    printf("PID %5d (PPID %5d) i = %d: child at work\n", pid, (int)getppid(), i);
    printf("FD {%d, %d, %d, %d}\n", i_pipe[0], i_pipe[1], o_pipe[0], o_pipe[1]);
    check_fds();

    srand(pid);
    close(i_pipe[1]);
    if (read(i_pipe[0], &winner, sizeof(winner)) != sizeof(winner))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to read entry from fd %d (%d: %s)\n",
                pid, i_pipe[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pr_result("Incoming bid", &winner);

    int newValue = new_bid();
    printf("PID: %5d, new offer %5d\n", pid, newValue);

    if (newValue > winner.val)
    {
        winner.node = i;
        winner.val = newValue;
        winner.pid = pid;
    }

    close(o_pipe[0]);
    pr_result("Outgoing bid", &winner);
    if (write(o_pipe[1], &winner, sizeof(winner)) != sizeof(winner))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to write entry to fd %d (%d: %s)\n",
                pid, o_pipe[1], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (read(i_pipe[0], &winner, sizeof(winner)) != sizeof(winner))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    pr_result("Final winner", &winner);
    close(i_pipe[0]);

    /* Relay final result to next process */
    if (write(o_pipe[1], &winner, sizeof(winner)) != sizeof(winner))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to write entry to fd %d (%d: %s)\n",
                pid, o_pipe[1], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(o_pipe[1]);

    /* There should be no children */
    no_children();
    check_fds();
    exit(i);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int numproc = 4;
    if (argc > 1)
        numproc = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (numproc < 2 || numproc > 10)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Number of processes %d is out of the range 2..10\n", numproc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int seed = time(NULL);
    printf("%5d: seed: %d\n", (int)getpid(), seed);
    srand(seed);

    int tube[numproc][2];

    mk_channel(0, tube[0]);
    mk_channel(1, tube[1]);

    for (int i = 1; i < numproc; ++i)
    {
        if (i + 1 < numproc)
            mk_channel(i + 1, tube[i + 1]);
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "fork error for child %d (%d: %s)\n", i, errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
            {
                if ((i + 1) % numproc != c)
                {
                    printf("%5d: closing %2d and %2d\n", (int)getpid(), tube[c][0], tube[c][1]);
                    close(tube[c][0]);
                    close(tube[c][1]);
                }
            }
            be_childish(i, tube[i], tube[(i+1) % numproc]);
        }
    }

    for (int c = 2; c < numproc; c++)
    {
        printf("%5d: closing %2d and %2d\n", (int)getpid(), tube[c][0], tube[c][1]);
        close(tube[c][0]);
        close(tube[c][1]);
    }

    be_parental(tube[0], tube[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Example run (6 processes requested):

```
$ pipe97 6
53200: seed: 1618329579
53200: C0(3,4)
53200: C1(5,6)
53200: C2(7,8)
53200: C3(9,10)
53201: closing  3 and  4
53200: C4(11,12)
PID 53201 (PPID 53200) i = 1: child at work
FD {5, 6, 7, 8}
PID 53201: ooo--oooo-----------
53202: closing  3 and  4
53200: C5(13,14)
53202: closing  5 and  6
PID 53202 (PPID 53200) i = 2: child at work
FD {7, 8, 9, 10}
PID 53202: ooo----oooo---------
53203: closing  3 and  4
53203: closing  5 and  6
53203: closing  7 and  8
PID 53203 (PPID 53200) i = 3: child at work
FD {9, 10, 11, 12}
PID 53203: ooo------oooo-------
53204: closing  3 and  4
53204: closing  5 and  6
53200: closing  7 and  8
53204: closing  7 and  8
53204: closing  9 and 10
53200: closing  9 and 10
PID 53204 (PPID 53200) i = 4: child at work
53200: closing 11 and 12
FD {11, 12, 13, 14}
53200: closing 13 and 14
PID 53200 (PPID   828): parent at work
FD {3, 4, 5, 6}
PID 53204: ooo--------oooo-----
PID 53200: ooooooo-------------
Opening bid:  PID = 53200, PPID =   828, Node = 0 (PID 53200), Value =  4998
Writing opening bid to fd 6
Incoming bid: PID = 53201, PPID = 53200, Node = 0 (PID 53200), Value =  4998
PID: 53201, new offer  9207
Outgoing bid: PID = 53201, PPID = 53200, Node = 1 (PID 53201), Value =  9207
Incoming bid: PID = 53202, PPID = 53200, Node = 1 (PID 53201), Value =  9207
PID: 53202, new offer  6014
Outgoing bid: PID = 53202, PPID = 53200, Node = 1 (PID 53201), Value =  9207
Incoming bid: PID = 53203, PPID = 53200, Node = 1 (PID 53201), Value =  9207
53205: closing  5 and  6
PID: 53203, new offer  2821
Outgoing bid: PID = 53203, PPID = 53200, Node = 1 (PID 53201), Value =  9207
Incoming bid: PID = 53204, PPID = 53200, Node = 1 (PID 53201), Value =  9207
PID: 53204, new offer  9628
Outgoing bid: PID = 53204, PPID = 53200, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
53205: closing  7 and  8
53205: closing  9 and 10
53205: closing 11 and 12
PID 53205 (PPID 53200) i = 5: child at work
FD {13, 14, 3, 4}
PID 53205: ooooo--------oo-----
Incoming bid: PID = 53205, PPID = 53200, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
PID: 53205, new offer  6435
Outgoing bid: PID = 53205, PPID = 53200, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
Winning node: PID = 53200, PPID =   828, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
Final winner: PID = 53201, PPID = 53200, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
Final winner: PID = 53202, PPID = 53200, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
PID 53201: ooo-----------------
Final winner: PID = 53203, PPID = 53200, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
PID 53202: ooo-----------------
PID 53203: ooo-----------------
Final winner: PID = 53204, PPID = 53200, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
Final winner: PID = 53205, PPID = 53200, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
PID 53204: ooo-----------------
PID 53205: ooo-----------------
Recirculated: PID = 53200, PPID =   828, Node = 4 (PID 53204), Value =  9628
PID 53200: child 53201 exited 0x0100
PID 53200: child 53203 exited 0x0300
PID 53200: child 53202 exited 0x0200
PID 53200: child 53204 exited 0x0400
PID 53200: child 53205 exited 0x0500
PID 53200: ooo-----------------
$
```

Note that the code is careful to close unnecessary file descriptors before calling the `be_childish()` or `be_parental()` functions.  The program works OK without those loops.